# How to return a table from a formula in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 9 dropdown menus. At level 0 the user choice is default for all other levels, at level 1-8 the user has an option to overwrite the first choice for that particular level only.

So for example, a level 0 you make the choice between Kabalite Warrior and Wych, and at level 4-8 you can choose to overwrite with a level in Skyterror.

Each level gets you a bunch of stuff which I have in individual tables and in one giant table. Each level has between 20-26 rows worth of stuff. What I want to do is from this dropdown menu return the relevant tables.

So if a player chooses at level 0 Kabalite Warrior then I want to generate a table (or separate tables for each level) with everything they would get from that. Then if a player chooses another dropdown that overwrites the appropriate level with the replacement stuff. So if they choose Skyterror at rank 4 it would overwrite Kabalite Warrior at rank 4, or if they choose it at rank 5 it would overwrite rank 5.

The way the data is organised is that each level has a column for rank, and a column for (let's use this word) class. So Kabalite rank 0 is KW 0 stuff you get. Note that for the choices after level 0 the level is the rank it can be first chosen at but (so Skyterror is ST 4 even though there is no ST 5, 6, 7 or 8)

Happy to share the file if needed, any help would be appreciated. I know absolutely nothing about VBA so I'm really hoping that I can avoid using that.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: I tried VLOOKUP and INDEX but as far as I'm aware they're only able of returning a row and INDEX requires positioning which isn't something I want to do since it's to look nice for the user and it can be extended with more tables and options. 

As I said I have no experience with VBA (and my one foray on the same program to try and count coloured cells refused to work).

Comment: These things can be hard to visualize in the abstract.  Can you add a diagram or screenshot, or draw something in crayon on a napkin of what you're trying to do?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kpqusfX.png

Here you go.

Top left: the dropdown.
Mid Left - What the options are on each drop down.
Bottom Left - Example of what the ranks are (all of them are on DE Code sheet) specifically for the Skyterror

On the right is where I want it to insert the rows and table, based off the rank and the name.

Comment: Still looking for help with this, haven't figured out how to do it.